# How do you update the Window's Desktop WorkingArea?

Tags: c#, windows, shell, desktop

I am developing a security and kiosk library in my framework. The problem here is I have the proper methods and routines to disable various features of the Windows Shell. The main feature I am discussing here is the Windows Taskbar.

I have properly disabled, and hid the Windows Taskbar. The problem is that the WorkingArea of the Window's desktop is not updated by ShowWindow/EnableWindow calls to the Taskbar, and still leaves the reserved space for the Taskbar on the desktop.

After reading almost all the topics regarding this, I am dissappointed. I am not looking to simply make my program "Full Screen", "Top Most", those are not acceptable answers. I am actually looking to either unregister the Taskbar as an AppBar, or update the WorkingArea. Any other solution is not what I am looking for as they are just "workarounds" and not actually resolutions.

Any links, whitepapers, or code samples/guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to be more flexible if you want a solution.  The only odds you'll have for a 'perfect' solution is SHAppBarMessage with ABM_REMOVE.  The odds aren't good, especially on Win7.  I don't want to try this myself, I like my taskbar :)

Comment: It seems that internally the Windows Shell ignores SHAppBarMessages went to the Taskbar after Windows XP SP3, so it's no longer a possibility with the changes to User32.dll. Which means you cannot even set the taskbar to AutoHide via SHAppBar message and then hide/disable it, so there really is no solution here for my requirements.